# unable to display multiple products order by desc

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where users can get books on rent, user can order books as per their requirements. There is one business logic, where we are showing the count of the same name of books, with their respective different book id. All works fine, but when the user orders books, the user gets the same id book, which other users have bought. To solve this I made 1 column(book_stock) where, if the user buys the book book_stock column will update to 0 else it will stay 1. This logic works fine, but when all books are purchased by the user, the book gets invisible from the website, because all books book_stock columns are updated to 0. But I want to show that book on the front end as out of stock, so user can get to know we have books but currently it's out of stock.

Below is a MySQL query which is used to display books on frontend

```
SELECT DISTINCT book_name, book_id, cats_id, book_author, book_author1, book_author2, book_author3, book_author4, book_author5, book_author6, book_rating, book_front_img, book_status, book_lan, book_stock, trends FROM `book_table` HAVING cats_id = '14' AND book_status = 1 ORDER BY book_stock DESC
```

I tried to use order by clause to show the book as per book_stock = 1, but it's not working
please let me know where I'm making things wrong.

Comment: Remove `AND book_status = 1` and instead put something in your UI which reads the book_status field and displays an appropriate message if it's out of stock (and maybe disables the button for ordering the book).

Comment: BTW your database looks like it's badly denormalised. I suggest taking a course in relational database design before you create any further problems for yourself. Also it looks like maybe you have the a row for every copy of the same book that you stock? That's probably not a great design either - instead of doing that and having book_status, why not just list each book once in the database and then have "total_copies" and "available_copies" columns to keep track of how many you own and how many are in stock?

Comment: @ADyson Yes I have a separate row for every copy because every book has its unique id, which is used to track by the admin

Comment: Well then it would make sense to have one entry for the book so you don't duplicate the basic details, then a sub table (with foreign key to the main one) containing (in each row) the overall book ID, the ID of the specific copy, and its availability.

Comment: Please post your table schema and sample data